# Why are some Vue components rendered sometimes only after hovering over them?

Tags: vue.js

One of my views has a component, which is only shown after data has been stored in Vuex

```
      <MyComponent v-if="dataFetched"/>
```

MyComponent is a pretty straight forward component. It contains several components which in turn contain buttons.

Sometimes when the view is accessed, the buttons are not rendered correctly before mouse is hovered on top of them. Sometimes none of the buttons are visible at all, sometimes one, two or three of the buttons are shown without the text. And sometimes they are rendered perfectly. The buttons do not implement mouse over events.

I cannot reproduce this locally, but it happens quite often when the application is run on server.

One of the buttons not rendered correctly is very simple:

```
<template>
  <span>
    <base-button
      v-on:click="logout()"
      >{{ $t("logout") }}
    </base-button>
  </span>
</template>
```

Hopefully the video makes it clear what's happening. Sorry that the dimensions of the video are not correct.

The button which is correctly drawn in the video is part of the main component. Buttons having issues are included in sub components.

There is also some text below the buttons and the text is always rendered correctly.

I am using vue-argon design system.

[image]

Comment: The question doesn't make sense in general. This depends on your case. Probably a problem with reactivity or CSS bug

Comment: But how should it be debugged?

Comment: I would look in the console to see if the buttons actually have content while they are showing empty. Since their sizing fits, probably the text is there but not showing, so to me it looks like it is more likely to be a CSS issue.

Comment: @MatthiasS you're correct, buttons seem to be in DOM.